# What's the difference between isPrototypeOf and instanceof in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, instanceof

In some of my own older code, I use the following:

```
Object.prototype.instanceOf = function( iface )
{
 return iface.prototype.isPrototypeOf( this );
};
```

Then I do (for example)

```
[].instanceOf( Array )
```

This works, but it seems the following would do the same:

```
[] instanceof Array
```

Now, surely this is only a very simple example. My question therefore is:

Is `a instanceof b` *ALWAYS* the same as `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` ?

Comment: While you can always use `instanceof` (with constructors on the RHS), not all objects might inherit from `Object.prototype`. `Object.create(null) instanceof Something` and `({}).instanceOf({prototype:Something.prototype})` will work (and yield `false`) where the reverse would fail.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, they do the same thing, both traverse up the prototype chain looking for an specific object in it.

The difference between both is *what they are*, and how you use them, e.g. the [`isPrototypeOf`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.6) is *a function* available on the `Object.prototype` object, it lets you test if *an specific object* is in the prototype chain of another, since this method is defined on `Object.prototype`, it is be available for all objects.

[`instanceof`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.6) is *an operator* and it expects two operands, an object and a [Constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function), it will test if the passed function `prototype` property exists on the chain of the object (via the [`[[HasInstance]](V)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function) internal operation, available only in Function objects).

For example:

```
function A () {
  this.a = 1;
}
function B () {
  this.b = 2;
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function C () {
  this.c = 3;
}
C.prototype = new B();
C.prototype.constructor = C;

var c = new C();

// instanceof expects a constructor function

c instanceof A; // true
c instanceof B; // true
c instanceof C; // true

// isPrototypeOf, can be used on any object
A.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c); // true
B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c); // true
C.prototype.isPrototypeOf(c); // true
```

Comment: So, the only difference is, that I can use isPrototypeOf, if I have only the prototype, whereas I need the constructor for instanceof? (Making my function really identical to instanceof?)

Comment: Your text answer is useful, your code example is less. (It does only show equal aspects but no differences.) However it raises another question to me: That is ".constructor" for? I've seen such code in some places, but never wrote that myself and I don't seem to have needed it. (I usually had something like `C.prototype.clazz = C;` tough.) Why do people set constructor?

Comment: @Steffen Heil: the code written by CMS is clear enough I think, it uses the most simple and known (though it is not the most effective) way to inherit in JavaScript between constructors. Try to delete the line `B.prototype.constructor = B` and inspect the constructor of an instance of B: `alert((new B).constructor)` and you'll see the A function constructor. By doing that, he assures himself to find, as a constructor of all the instances of B, just B.

Comment: @CMS Can you also say, `instanceof` is mainly for pseudo-classical inheritance, as it relies on `B.prototype`, and `B`, which is a "constructor". So what if `B.prototype` and `B` are not used, so there is no constructor, when the JavaScript program is written strictly in a prototypal inheritance way? In this case, then `animal.isPrototypeOf(woofie)` can be used

Comment: AFAIK `instanceof` doesn't work when not using a constructor function, e.g. `Object.create`. Seems to have all kind of other problems as well: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

Comment: Some interesting extra info about speed of both functions:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/unnZizdyItYS7R2DDeHaGSLAmRpFwAng2rSoLJLfU1t2XGf7vTpS1bOeseiBqAdHWmYm7O3SPc8uncHNr7Iy8IRrwQT_1d6CQy4brLlQL0IQJ7sW0pBoHH8ourn0hRqBjj9efrti
For more info:
https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2017/08/v8-release-61.html?m=1

Answer (score 9):

> Is `a instanceof b` ALWAYS the same as `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` ?

**No, `a instanceof b` will not always behave the same as `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)`.**

[CMS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464800/10367549) pointed out that they differ in *what they are* (one is an operator and the other is a built-in method available on the `Object.prototype` object). This is correct, however there are also some special cases for which `a instanceof b` will result in a `TypeError` while `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` will work just fine and vice versa.

### Difference #1

The right-hand side of `instanceof` is expected to be a constructor function.

If `b` is not a function:

- `a instanceof b` will result in a `TypeError`.
- `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` will work just fine.

```js
const b = {
    prototype: {}
};
const a = Object.create( b.prototype );

console.log( b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a) );    // true
console.log( a instanceof b );                  // TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
```

### Difference #2

When using `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)`, `b.prototype` should be inheriting from `Object.prototype`:

If `b.prototype` has not access to the `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()` method:

- `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` will result in a `TypeError`.
- `a instanceof b` will work just fine.

```js
function B() {};
B.prototype = Object.create( null );

const a = new B();

console.log( a instanceof B );              // true
console.log( B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a) ) // TypeError: B.prototype.isPrototypeOf is not a function
```

### Difference #3

If the right-hand side of `instanceof` is a bound function, it is treated equivalently to its target function.

If b is a bound function:

- `a instanceof b` will work just fine.
- `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` will result in a `TypeError` (bound functions don't have a `prototype` property).

```js
function B() {};
const BoundB = B.bind( null );
const a = new B();

console.log( a instanceof BoundB );              // true
console.log( BoundB.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a) ) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPrototypeOf' of undefined
```

### Conclusion

- If you are dealing with prototypal inheritance established through `Object.create()`, without the use of constructors, you should probably be using the `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()` method (indeed the use cases of `instanceof` are more restricted in that `instanceof` expects its right-hand side parameter to be a constructor function).
- If you are dealing with constructors you will be slightly safer by using the `instanceof` operator (you will be able to cover bound functions as well as the cases where `Object.prototype` does not lie in the prototype chain of `Constructor.prototype`).

Comment: Note that the issue encountered in _Difference #2_ could also be avoided by using `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(B.prototype, a)`

Comment: see https://www.quora.com/Javascript-is-the-behavior-of-this-call-defined-Object-prototype-isPrototypeOf-call-a-b

Comment: Great answer. I would also like to add for anyone who cares that both `instanceof` and `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf` were added to JavaScript in ES3 ([ECMA-262 3rd Edition](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_3rd_edition_december_1999.pdf)). And I recommend avoiding them both in most cases in favor of `typeof` and other methods of type testing.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence and truthiness differ since one is an expression and the other is a method call. One thing to emphasize is that both **traverse the prototype chain**, so you cannot assume that there is a one-to-one mapping between a matching prototype and the object in question:

```js
var i = 0;

function foo()
{
console.log("foo");
console.log(i++ + ": " + Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function) ) //true

console.log(i++ + ": " + Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object) ) //true

console.log(i++ + ": " + RegExp.prototype.isPrototypeOf( RegExp(/foo/) ) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf( RegExp(/foo/) ) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf( RegExp(/foo/) ) ) //false
console.log(i++ + ": " + Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Math) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + Math.isPrototypeOf(Math) ) //false
}

function bar()
{
console.log("bar");
console.log(i++ + ": " + (Object instanceof Object) ) //true

console.log(i++ + ": " + (Function instanceof Function) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + (Function instanceof Object) ) //true

console.log(i++ + ": " + (RegExp(/foo/) instanceof RegExp) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + (RegExp(/foo/) instanceof Object)  ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + (RegExp(/foo/) instanceof Function) ) //false
console.log(i++ + ": " + (Math instanceof Object) ) //true
console.log(i++ + ": " + (Math instanceof Math) ) //error
}
try
  {
  foo()
  }
catch(e)
  {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
finally
  {
  try
    {
    bar();
    }
  catch(e)
    {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  }
```

**References**

- [Classes in ECMAScript 6 (final semantics)](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)