# JavaScript isPrototypeOf vs instanceof usage

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following:

```
function Super() {
      // init code
}

function Sub() {
      Super.call(this);
      // other init code
}

Sub.prototype = new Super();

var sub = new Sub();
```

Then, in some other part of our ocde, we can use either of the following to check for the relationship:

```
sub instanceof Super;
```

or

```
Super.prototype.isPrototypeOf( sub )
```

Either way, we need to have both the object (sub), and the parent constructor (Super).  So, is there any reason why you'd use one vs the other?  Is there some other situation where the distinction is more clear?

I've already carefully read [2464426](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464426/whats-the-difference-between-isprototypeof-and-instanceof-in-javascript), but didn't find a specific enough answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need the isPrototypeOf at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972991/why-do-we-need-the-isprototypeof-at-all)

Comment: Based on the OP's comment, I'd say this question is closer to "Why do we need `instanceof` at all?" but I agree that it's probably close enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between isPrototypeOf and instanceof in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464426/whats-the-difference-between-isprototypeof-and-instanceof-in-javascript)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Imagine you *don't use constructors* in your code, but instead use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to generate objects with a particular prototype. Your program might be architected to use no constructors at all:

```
var superProto = {
    // some super properties
}

var subProto = Object.create(superProto);
subProto.someProp = 5;

var sub = Object.create(subProto);

console.log(superProto.isPrototypeOf(sub));  // true
console.log(sub instanceof superProto);      // TypeError
```

Here, you don't have a constructor function to use with `instanceof`. You can only use `subProto.isPrototypeOf(sub)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I have one quick follow up:  Why do we need instanceof, since isPrototypeOf would seem to work in all cases?  Is it historical or are there performance advantages, or something else?

Comment: @user1689498 Simply because `isPrototypeOf` has been implemented later.

Comment: @user1689498: `instanceof` is older, I believe, and looks similar to Java, which was a big deal when JavaScript was first introduced.  It also is a little cleaner.  But yes, `isPrototypeOf` is the more generally useful one.

Answer (score 13):

It makes little difference when you use constructor functions.  `instanceof` is a little cleaner, perhaps.  But when you don't...:

```
var human = {mortal: true}
var socrates = Object.create(human);
human.isPrototypeOf(socrates); //=> true
socrates instanceof human; //=> ERROR!
```

So `isPrototypeOf` is more general.

Comment: Great! :) But one thing. «human» in this example should be a «Human». I mean it should be a class (All people), not a single instance (a human).

Comment: @NaeelMaqsudov: Beware analogies between languages.  Javascript has no classes.  Even in when the travesty of `class` syntactic sugar is added in ES6, the language will still not have something really like, say, Java classes.  Prototypal inheritance has some parallels with classical inheritance, but the analogies are rough ones.  In any way of doing inheritance, there will be an object such as this --- perhaps the prototype of a constructor function.  But note:  `var naeel = Object.create(human);  naeel instanceof human; //=> true`.  This strips away some of the sugar of constructor functions.

Comment: Sorry,  bad cut-and-paste error.  `naeel instanceof human;  //=> ERROR.`  But `human.prototypOf(naeel);  //=> true`.

Comment: Wow.  I think I need some caffeine.  `isPrototypeOf`.

Comment: @NaeelMaqsudov: Most importantly, note that although historically constructor functions predated `Object.create`, it's the latter which is the more fundamental construct.  The constructor function could be easily built on top of `Object.create`, which is the fundamental behavior, and `instanceOf` could be built on top of `isPrototypeOf`, but the reverse of these are not true, or at least have no obvious solutions.  Using this mechanism, you can just as easily claim that all such constructed object are 'human' objects as you can with the constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf):

> `isPrototypeOf()` differs from the `instanceof` operator. In the expression `object instanceof AFunction`, the object prototype chain is checked against `AFunction.prototype`, not against `AFunction` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var neuesArray = Object.create(Array);

Array.isPrototypeOf(neuesArray);            // true
neuesArray instanceof Array                 // false
neuesArray instanceof Object                // true
Array.isArray(neuesArray);                  // false
Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(neuesArray);  // false
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(neuesArray); // true
```

Do you understand my friend :) - is simple

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to convey and how it's relevant to the problem. Can you add explanation to this?

Comment: the difference by "instanceof" - Operator and the Object.isPrototypeOf() - methode - or?

Answer (score 0):

Just complement [@apsillers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343687/5238583)

`object instanceof constructor`

```
var superProto = {}

// subProto.__proto__.__proto__ === superProto
var subProto = Object.create(superProto);
subProto.someProp = 5;
// sub.__proto__.__proto__ === subProto
var sub = Object.create(subProto);

console.log(superProto.isPrototypeOf(sub)); // true
console.log(sub instanceof superProto); // TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

// helper utility to see if `o1` is
// related to (delegates to) `o2`
function isRelatedTo(o1, o2) {
  function F(){}
  F.prototype = o2;
  // ensure the right-hand side of 'instanceof' is callable
  return o1 instanceof F; 
}
isRelatedTo( b, a );
```

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

`instanceof` need the right-hand value to be callable, which means it must be a function(MDN call it as the constructor)

and `instanceof` tests the presence of `constructor.prototype` in object's prototype chain.

but `isPrototypeOf()` don't have such limit. While `instanceof` checks `superProto.prototype`, `isPrototypeOf()` checks `superProto` directly.