# Object.getPrototypeOf and example.isPrototypeOf(obj) gave confusing results

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I read that `Object.gePrototypeOf(someObject)` returns the prototype of the passed object and `aPrototype.isPrototypeOf(someObject)` returns true if `aPrototype` is the prototype of `someObject`. It is obvious to me that if `Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject)` returns a prototype named `aPrototype`, then `aPrototype.isPrototypeOf(someObject)` will return true. But it's not happening in my code:

```
function person(fname, lname)
{
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;   
}

var arun = new person('Arun', 'Jaiswal');

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(arun));  //person
console.log(person.isPrototypeOf(arun));   //false
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Nope. `isPrototypeOf` tests the whole chain just as well, the difference to `instanceof` is that it doesn't take constructor function whose `.prototype` is uses to look for in the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf), syntax of `isPrototype` is

```
prototypeObj.isPrototypeOf(obj)
```

Also refer [isPrototypeOf vs instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343545/javascript-isprototypeof-vs-instanceof-usage)

```js
function person(fname, lname)
{
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;   
}

var arun = new person('Arun', 'Jaiswal');

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(arun));  //person
console.log(person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arun));
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype of `arun` is not `person` but `person.prototype`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(arun) === person.prototype; // true
person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arun); // true
```

Comment: Then what exactly is the job of isPrototypeOf() ?

Answer (score 0):

`isPrototypeOf` is not called on the constructor itself, but on the constructor's prototype property.

```
alert(person.prototype.isPrototypeOf(arun)); // true
```

This means that the prototype of arun is not `person`, but `person.prototype`.